# Spatial discretization of Brownian motion/Wiener process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a spatio-temporal Brownian motion/Wiener process $dW(x,t)$ for $x\in [0,1]$ and $t\geq 0$. I want to come up with an "$n$-sized" discretization of the form $dW_n(x_i,t)$ for $i=1,\dots, n$, and I'm not sure how to go about this.

I know that one can discretize in time as in [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=184dbc45c7a11d25908266871c24836acb75d53e), where the discrete version is just a piecewise constant function that takes random values at each step.

For the spatial discretization, my first thought is that we can simply take a "slice" of $dW(x,t)$ at each point $x_i$, and define $dW_n(x_i,t)$ that way. Is that correct? And how would we go about proving convergence, i.e. something like $\mathbb{E} \|dW_n(x_i, t) - dW(x,t) \|^2_2 \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I think example 10.31 in An introduction to computational SPDEs by Lord, Shardlow and Powell might contain the explanation and proof you are looking for.

Comment: @C.Hamster thank you for the reference. This paper also does something similar:  (section 3.2 in particular) https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036142901387956?journalCode=sjnaam

Comment: @C.Hamster Both of those seem to deal with time-and-space discretizations but not space-discretization of a time-and-space noise. Is that a problem, or can I discretize the equation as if it were only in space, then make everything time-dependent?

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree. If you look at the equation above 10.42, you'll see that the SPDE is approximated by a set of SDEs at the spatial discretization points. Each SDE is driven by white noise. Note that the variance of the noise is $dt/dx$, hence the variance of the noise in time does depend on your spatial discretization.